# Error while using history object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When i use history.push(/myappointment), the page route to the MyAppointment component. Now in MyAppointment component, there is a button, on clicking that button i call a function "Click" in which i do history.push(/newAppointment) to go to the "newAppointment" component, but this time the error is shown as :-

```
MyAppointment.tsx:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
```

Some Few lines of both components are:-

The code for the first component is:-

```
interface ILoginPageProps {
  history: any;
}

class Login extends React.Component<ILoginPageProps, {}> {
  componentDidUpdate() {
      const { history } = this.props;
      history.push({"/myappointment"});
    }
  }
```

The code for the MyAppointment is :-

```
interface IProps {
  history: any;
}
rightClick() {
    //console.log("hii");
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push("/newAppointment");
  }
```

The Route file code is :-

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(constants)}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/myAppointment" component={MyAppointment} />
          <Route
            path="/myAppointment/newAppointment"
            component={NewAppointment}
          />
        </Switch>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo in this part. You are trying to destruct `history` from `this.props.history`.

```
const { history } = this.props.history; // this probably should be `this.props` instead

history.push("/newAppointment");
```

Comment: i changed "this.props.history" to "this.props", but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Rohitchauhan Hm, I assume you are using react-router right? Can you update your question with your package.json file, and the file where you put your routes?

Comment: @Rohitchauhan What version of react-router are you using? Is `App` the entry point for your react app? If not, can you show the entry file?

Answer (score 0):

You either want a **[Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)** component to route to another page.

> Provides declarative, accessible navigation around your application

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
...
<Link to="/newAppointment" />
```

Or if you want to push programatically you must wrap your component with the **[withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)** HOC

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest
>   Route's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter
>   will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped
>   component whenever it renders.

```
@withRouter
class Login extends React.Component
....
```

or if you prefer

```
class Login extends React.Component
...
export default withRouter(Login);
```